# ReactJS - Set unique state for dynamically generated items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching some data from the server to populate a list of items, and each item got a onClick event binded to the items id, that changes the UI to be disabled when clicked.

**My problem** is that the UI changes to disabled perfectly on the first click, but when I go on to click on the next item it resets the first on, so there is only one button disabled at a time. How do I make it so I can disable all the items I want, without resetting the previous ones?

**Here is my component:**

```
class Video extends Component {
constructor () {
 super()
  this.state = {
   isDisabled: false
 }
}


handleClick(frag, voted, event){
 event.preventDefault()

 this.setState({
   isDisabled: {
      [frag]: true
   }
 })
}
```

**Snippet of what I return in the UI that changes the disabled button**

```
 <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, frags.id, frags.voted)} disabled={this.state.isDisabled[frags.id]} className="rating-heart-2">
     <i className="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </button>
```

I would really appreciate all tips!

Comment: it's not clear how `this.state.hasRated` is altered. It's also confusing because you change `isDisabled` but use `hasRated` to determine whether or not the button should be disabled.

Comment: Did you solved your problem? Can you post the answer?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that when you call setState, you are overriding the previous value of the `isDisabled`.

You can do something like this:

```
handleClick(frag, voted, event){
 event.preventDefault()

 this.setState({
   isDisabled: {
      ...this.state.isDisabled,
      [frag]: true
   }
 })
}
```

Comment: When using ...this.state.isDisabled i get a Unexpected token error, any suggestions?

Comment: You must enable the [object rest spread transformer](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/), or you can use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) function

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is a bit confusing because in the jsx you have `this.state.hasRated` to disable the button and in the handleClick you have a `isDisabled` object.

I followed the jsx approach and I add the frag id the `hasRated` object with the value true to disable a button each it is clicked.

You can run the following snippet to see the output of the code:

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      frags: [],
      hasRated: {}
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        frags: [{
          id: 1,
          voted: false
        }, {
          id: 2,
          voted: false
        }, {
          id: 3,
          voted: false
        }]
      });
    }, 500);
  }

  handleClick(id, voted) {
    return (event) => {
      this.setState({
        hasRated: {
          ...this.state.hasRated,
          [id]: true
        }
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const items = this.state.frags.map(frag => ( <
      button 
      key={frag.id}
      onClick = {
        this.handleClick(frag.id, frag.voted)
      }
      disabled = {
        this.state.hasRated[frag.id]
      }
      className = "rating-heart-2" >
      Button <
      /button>
    ));

    return (
      <div>
        {items}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < Example / > , document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: My bad, it should have been isDisabled not hasRated - But I'm getting an Unexpected token error when using ...this.state.hasRated. Any suggestions? :)

Comment: What do you have in .babelrc file? Its a problem with converting the code from es6 to es5

Comment: You might want to add the following transformation to your babel: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-object-rest-spread/

Comment: I got "babel-core": "^6.22.1", "babel-loader": "^6.2.10", "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0", "babel-preset-react": "^6.22.0" installed. I think I found a solution, but thanks for your time :)